# MVC: How to send partial updates for only specific fields in the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a multi-step form in MVC:

1. At Step1 we ask name, mobile, email of the user.
2. At Step2 we ask high school grades, academic achievements of the user.
3. At Step3 we ask job details, annual salary.

The C# ViewModel class has all these properties i.e. name,mobile,email,grades,achievements,job,salary.

We have single update screen where user can update any of these details. Currently, if user edits his mobile, we have to send the complete ViewModel class again with all these 7 properties. This is an overkill.

How can we send only the updated fields by the user and not send entire object i.e. something like PATCH in MVC too?

One way could be:- If user changes mobile, we add mobile with number to javascript object and do similar thing for other controls too like name, salary etc. Then at server side, we fetch db object and check what all has changed except for default values of the field. This is inefficient as we have to update all the fields. This is also not full proof as user may need to edit back value to default value of data-type.

How can we do this?

Comment: If you're talking about 7 fields and not 70, the best would be to send the whole VM as it's the standard way and it won't be so inefficient. By my opinion, creating some mechanism of sending fields one by one with some checking logic and comparing them with DB would be worse overkill for this case.

Comment: @M.Pipal: No, I have oversimplified the problem, its actually many more fields